# MySQL Query : I want to use aggregate function between two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have two tables
Customer table

```
+--------+---------+
| refno  | deposit |
+--------+---------+
| 1/13   |     -10 |
| 10/13  |     500 |
| 100/13 |       0 |
| 101/13 |     250 |
| 102/13 |    1000 |
+--------+---------+
```

Ledger Table

```
+--------+----------+------+----------+
| refno  | quantity | rate | recieved |
+--------+----------+------+----------+
| 1/13   |        2 |   70 |        0 |
| 10/13  |        3 |   80 |        0 |
| 100/13 |        3 |   60 |        0 |
| 101/13 |        4 |   60 |        0 |
| 102/13 |       10 |   65 |        0 |
+--------+----------+------+----------+
```

I want to customer column(deposit) added in ledger column (total)
I don't want to create another table.
i want

```
refno | total = customer.deposit+(ledger.quantity*ledger.rate-ledger.received)
1/13  | -200
10/13 | 4210
100/13| 625
101/13| 280
102/13| 1000
```

Regards,

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  Is there a problem with doing a simple join?

Comment: do you want to add or subtract total and deposit or do you want a table customer with the three columns refno, total, deposit?

Comment: could you provide expected output after the query executed?

Comment: @har07
i want
refno | total
1/13  | -200
10/13 | 4210
100/13| 625
101/13|280
102/13|1000

Comment: @user3306314 . . . Please edit your question to show the layout of the `ledger` table.

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.refno,  c.deposit + l.total
from customer c join ledger l on c.refno = l.refno
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select l.refno, l.total, c.deposit, l.total + coalesce(c.deposit, 0) as TotalWithDeposit
from ledger l left outer join
     customer c
     on l.refno = c.refno;
```

Your question mentions aggregate functions, but I don't see any aggregations going on.

EDIT:

```
select l.refno, l.total, c.deposit,
       c.deposit + (l.quantity * l.rate - l.received) as TotalWithDeposit
from ledger l left outer join
     customer c
     on l.refno = c.refno;
```

Comment: @user3306314 . . . The `TotalWithDeposit` column is not what you want?  How did it not work?

Comment: it executed but not giving the desired output as in question,
i want to mention  the total= ledger.rate*ledger.quantity

Comment: @user3306314 . . . You can substitute whatever query you used to get the results in the question for `ledger` in this query.

Answer (score 0):

If you have duplicate refno in Ledger, you can try this way :

```
select b.refno, b.total + IFNULL(a.deposit, 0) as total
from
    (select refno, sum(total) as total
    from Ledger
    group by refno) b
    inner join Customer a on a.refno = b.refno
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6fcd4/9)

Comment: i dont want to update my table 
i just want the result in select statement

Comment: how about the 2nd query above, does it work? do you have duplicate refno in Customer and Ledger table?

Comment: i have duplicate refno in ledger table

Comment: executing second query gives error
FUNCTION databasename.coalsece does not exist

Comment: Its executing but not giving the desired output
I want that answer that is in my question..

Comment: updated. tested in sqlfiddle, if anything still wrong edit data in sqlfiddle link above to reproduce the problem.

Comment: thanks for your so much coorporation,
I have updated schema in sql fiddle, i want rate*quantity-received amount to be subtracted from deposited amount..
your fiddle works correctly but not driving the exact output,

Comment: Already left my pc now, so can't help much from phone. Try to change this part in this answer: sum(total) to: sum(rate*quantity-received amount). Good luck

Comment: Thanks to all of you,
i got my solution answered :)

Answer (score 0):

I think author means update other than select from directly, but not sure which table used as basic table. For example, if we want to add value in Customer to that in Ledger, it should look like this:

update Ledger l inner join Cusomter c on l.refno = c.refno set l.total = l.total + c.deposit.